# What is inverted in A and B

Tags: inversion-of-control

We know the concept of `IOC(Inversion of Control)` and also we know how to use the concept in case of `Spring`. Now just want to know if there are two classes like A and B. If I use IOC for class A and B, what is inverted here? I provide below the code.

```
class A {
    B b;
    public A(B b) {
    }
}
```

So here we know that it is a case of constructor injection, but what is inverted here as part of IOC ? Please provide me an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Its a design patter related to removing dependency from your code. Now if you want to create the object of class A or class B you no more need to worry about how the object should be created.

```
class A {
    B b;
    public A() {
      b = new B();
    }
}
```

now in case of inversion of control

```
class A {
    IB b;  //IB is interface
    public A(IB b) {
      b = b;
    }
}
```

Now here your code is loosely coupled and you no need to worry about B's object creation

please refer the link [IOC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29271/Design-pattern-Inversion-of-control-and-Dependency)

Comment: It is not always necessary that you will always have a set of interfaces. Please explain in case of only two classes like A and B as I shown above.

Comment: Inversion of control is very broad term and it can be implemented in various  [ways to implement inversion of control](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/19/inversion-of-control-ioc-and-dependency-injection-di-patterns-in-spring-framework-and-related-interview-questions/)

Comment: Your trying it with spring?

Comment: I agree with the answers definition and I'd like to clarify by mentioning that the original question seems to be asking about whether or not class A or class B is the one doing the "Inversion of Control" which seems like the wrong question.  It is neither A nor B who is "in control" per se, but instead the one in "control" is the IoC system that is being used.  Being "in control" here generally means "the one who creates the objects" and so in your example neither A nor B should be creating anything, instead giving that "control" to the IoC system, such as Spring, HK2, Guice or others.